# Making the Dataview or ListView in ASP.NET using C# clickable and display the data using response.write?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do you make the dataview or listview clickable and when it clicks it does gets click It would fetch and display the row of data that you click using the `Response.Write`?

I have been stuck on this problem for a few days. Still no progress at all.

Comment: What is DataView/ListView? From which library?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.